# Sony cam API: Take picture method is very slow on Wifi cam DSC-QX30

Tags: android, camera, sony, sony-camera-api

After a lot of testing using your CameraRemoteSampleApp demo project, the method **JSONObject replyJson = mRemoteApi.actTakePicture();** takes from 2 to 4 seconds for retrieving the JSONObject.

Is it possibile to reduce this processing time?

Comment: How did you measure that time? From the moment of invocation the method or taking the photo by the camera? Does your camera have automatic image preview/cropping options set on?

Comment: In order to measure the time, I'm using a simple stopwatch class that uses System.currentTimeMillis() for making the calculation. I start the timer at the beginning of the method SimpleHttpClient.httpPost and stop it exactly after the OutputStreamWriter is populated and closed, right before the comment **// Read stream as String**.
I'm checking the option you are talking about and will let you know asap

Comment: This can also depend on how much time camera needs on focus. I will try to do some tests as well this week with my a6000.

Comment: Thank very much for the help. I cannot find the options you are talking about... I'm using PlayMemories Mobile app for checking them

Comment: Any news about that @kriskot ?

Comment: I’m working on iOS SDK. I want to capture images within short intervals like 2 or 3 secs. Did you find any workaround for this?